# html tag "data-url" not working when you add html from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, data-uri

I know from the title it's probably super confusing so let me explain.

On this page I have something like this:

```
  <div id="district_courses">
                    <?php foreach ($courses as $course) {
                        if ($course->group_type == 'D') {  ?>
                            <div id="course_nav_<?php echo $course->id; ?>" class="menu-item course" data-url="<?php echo base_url('/admin/uploads/course/' . $course->id); ?>">
                                <div><?php if ($isDistrict == TRUE) {
                                            echo $course->title . " <sapn style='font-size: 12px;'>(" . $course->pub_name . ")</span>";
                                        } else {
                                            echo $course->title;
                                        } ?></div>
                            </div>
                    <?php }
                    } ?>
                </div>
```

which works fine and the data-url is active when the element is clicked.  However, now there's a search function where I grab the data and put it in the empty div on the page

```
<div id="searched_courses">
                </div>
```

Here's the ajax call that gets the search data.  As you see I loop the results in javascript then put the code into the div above but now it seems with this code the data-url is inactive.  I can't click on the element and run the data url?

```
$("#search_courses").click(function() {
    var searchquery = $('#course_search_input').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/admin/uploads/course-search',
        data: {
            query: searchquery
        },
        success: function(response) {
            var courses = response.courses;
            var i;
            var html = '';
            for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
                //console.log(courses[i]['id']);
                html += '<div id="course_nav_' + courses[i]['id'] + '" class="menu-item course" data-url="/admin/uploads/course/' + courses[i]['id'] + '"> \
                        <div>' + courses[i]['title'] + ' <sapn style="font-size: 12px;">(' + courses[i]['pub_name'] + ')</span></div> \
                    </div>';
            }


            $('#super_district_courses').hide();
            $('#district_courses').hide();
            $('#school_courses').hide();
            $('#all_courses').hide();
            document.getElementById("searched_courses").innerHTML = html;
            
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The one that works uses base_url and the other doesn't. That might be your issue.

Comment: Yea that was my first thought and I put it in there.  Still did not work.

Comment: Did you try it like this? `data-url="<?php echo base_url('/admin/uploads/course/'); ?>'  + courses[i]['id'] +`

Comment: nope.  I'll try that now.  But I did try just hardcoding it like: data-url="<?php echo base_url('/admin/uploads/course/93'); ?>' "

Comment: didn't work but interesting try

Comment: I guess I'll just have to solve it by adding an onclick to the div that passes the id.  I did not want to have to do that because it's more code but nobody on here knows I guess.  I appreciate the help though @Musa

Comment: Hi, from active you mean display like link ? :P sorry for dumb question

Comment: not exactly.  it shows the link but the data-url when the element is clicked it goes to that url and does the functions needed.  When I put it in the ajax call it shows in the DOM how it's supposed to look but when the element is clicked the url is not fired as it should be

Comment: I ended up just putting on onclick event in the tag and it works.  It's a workaround but would be nice not to have to use the extra code